# How to access outside VIEWS on Activity from inside recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I created an Activity with TextView ,RecyclerView .
I want to access parent activity TextView from inside of a RecyclerView .
Please note I already loaded data in RecyclerView .

Kindly give any solution to access parent activity TextView.

Refer this code,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="MY TEXT VIEW"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I successfully loaded some data with RecyclerView(rv) through custom adapter ,

```
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
mAdapter = new custom_Adapter(this,loadData());
rv.setAdapter(mAdapter)
```

Now , From inside my custom adapter "onBindViewHolder"  **I want to access my parent activity TextView (tv) .** Kindly advise

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CartViewHolder holder, int position)  {
    ....
    }
```

Comment: share some code..!!

Comment: you're set the layout inflater, not? (you didn't add a code)... there are a lots of example on webweb, here is one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq2o4EbM74k

Comment: @AsfK , I already loaded data in RecyclerView without issue . I want to access my parent activity TextView (tv) .

Comment: @jankigadhiya  code added for your reference

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, in the onCreate() of your parent activity, you would assign an instance variable to hold a reference to the TextView.

```
TextView textView; // Your TextView

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize TextView so you can access it later
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_message);
    }
}
```

Now you would be able to access your TextView from within the overridden methods for Adapter.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CartViewHolder holder, int position)  {
    textView.setText("text here");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An object of the parent class should be created in the adapter class and should be set equal to the reference of parent class in the constructor in adapter class.
Your Adapter class constructor should be something like this:

```
    ParentActivity mParentActivity;
    public custom_Adapter(ParentActivity parentActivity,Something Else){
        this.mParentActivity=parentActivity;
    }
```

mParentActivity is an object of parent class and can be used to access anything public in your parent class like **mParentActivity.name**